# SQL Pagination including duplicate rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm having some trouble solving an issue with pagination in SQL.

I'm stuck trying to fill a @PageSize variable in my stored procedure that comes from some ODATA, However the value from ODATA doesn't get me what I'm after necessarily. My query you see returns results like this.

```
+----+----------+
| ID | PersonID |
+----+----------+
| 1  | 1        |
+----+----------+
| 1  | 2        |
+----+----------+
| 2  | 1        |
+----+----------+
| 2  | 2        |
+----+----------+
| 2  | 3        |
+----+----------+
| 3  | 4        |
+----+----------+
| 3  | 4        |
+----+----------+
```

Obviously if I got a @PageResult = 5 from OData, it would just return 5 rows, but I want it to return x occurrences of ID.

To demonstrate what I basically want, is that if my @PageSize is 1, my sproc return this.

```
+----+----------+
| ID | PersonID |
+----+----------+
| 1  | 1        |
+----+----------+
| 1  | 2        |
+----+----------+
```

If it is 2, I return this.

```
+----+----------+
| ID | PersonID |
+----+----------+
| 1  | 1        |
+----+----------+
| 1  | 2        |
+----+----------+
| 2  | 1        |
+----+----------+
| 2  | 2        |
+----+----------+
| 2  | 3        |
+----+----------+
```

And so on. I'm having no end of trouble trying to get it to return data this way, I've tried doing things like distinct top(@pagesize) ID but it always seems to get the order wrong so it misses ID's and dense_ranks don't appear to do the job either. I imagine this is causing me so much hassle because there is no default order in SQL so the solution is not so obvious. Can any of you suggest how I might achieve this?

The closest I've gotten is with this

```
SET @PageSize = (select COUNT(personId) from #temptable WHERE ID IN (SELECT DISTINCT TOP(@PageSize) ID From #temptable))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
declare @t table(ID int, PersonID int)

insert into @t(ID,PersonID) values
(1,1),(1,2),(2,1),(2,2),(2,3),(3,3),(3,4);



with q as
(
  select id, row_number() over (order by ID) rn
  from @t 
  group by id
)
select *
from @t  
where id in
(
   select id 
   from q
   where rn between 1 and 2
)
order by ID, PersonID
```

which outputs

```
ID          PersonID
----------- -----------
1           1
1           2
2           1
2           2
2           3

(5 rows affected)
```